# How can I highlight cells based on row and column values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I'm trying to highlight my row name and row value.

If currentRatio and over 1.4 highlight red

if quickRatio and over 32 highlight yellow

I'm having trouble getting my first test to run correctly.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'currentRatio' : [1.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.0],
                    'quickRatio' : [30, 37, 30, 35], })
print(df1.T)
```

This output

```
                 0     1     2     3
currentRatio   1.2   1.5   1.4   2.0
quickRatio    30.0  37.0  30.0  35.0
```

```
def color_row(row):
    pprint(row)
    if row.name == 'currentRatio:
        if row.value > 1.4:
            return pd.Series('background-color: red', row.index)

 display(df1.style.apply(color_row, axis=1))
```

The pprint row output is

```
index          currentRatio
0         1.2
1         1.5
2         1.14
3         1.2
4         1.352669417512594
```

Thank you for your time I any assistance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as a list comprehension with appropriate conditional logic

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'currentRatio' : [1.2, 1.5, 1.4, 2.0],
                    'quickRatio' : [30, 37, 30, 35], })

def color_row(row):
    return ['background-color: red' if v>=1.4 and i=="currentRatio" 
            else 'background-color: yellow' if v>=32 and i=="quickRatio" 
            else ""
            for i, v in row.items()]

df1.style.apply(color_row, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Rob this got me to the correct solution:

    return ['background-color: red' if v>=1.4 and row.name=="currentRatio" 
            else 'background-color: yellow' if row.name=="quickRatio" 
            else ""
            for v, i in row.items()]